# Javascript/Jquery: How can I embed a web page into another person's website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, embed, html

I am looking for a way to embed a website to a third party website. This will make my job much easier. I try searching for a way on stackoverflow, but my search results just showed me ways to add iframe if I owned the site, which in this case I don't. Any suggestions will be appreciated. This is an attempt to help me search for data. I ultimately plan to have multiple websites embed on a web page so I can search for the data on one web page instead of having to keep going back and forth across multiple web pages. For example, if I wanted to embed google.com website to stackoverflow so that way I can search for answers without having to leave stackoverflow or switch tabs.

Comment: Is there a non-malicious use case for this?

Comment: No, I don't attempt to harm anything. This is just for me to use as a way to search data without having to keep switching tabs. Makes my life easier. On the third party website, there is a huge space that I can embed a site on it so I don't keep going back and forth on tabs. I've plan to do have more than one website embed.

Comment: *a way to search data without having to keep switching tabs* How would this help you do that? Can you edit your question to clarify exactly what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Yes, I edit it to show what I am trying to do.

Comment: For example, if I wanted to embed google.com website to stackoverflow so I can search google without leaving stackoverflow.

Comment: I think your problem was that you were using the word "embed" in your search. If you just look for "view two sites in one tab" you'll find browser plugins that handle this. Otherwise you can create one page with two iframes, one with each site you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing what you are looking for is something like this. Assuming the site you want to embed into uses jQuery, you could try something like this this (but it won't work on the sites you mention as you hoped).

```
$('#sidebar').html('<iframe src="http://google.com"></iframe>');
```

In fact if you open up the console and try this on SO, you will see that you get an error because of the X-Frame-Options header is set to 'SAMEORIGIN' which basically says that Google doesn't allow itself to be embedded like that. If you try putting 'stackoverflow.com' you will get an alert saying that SO doesn't allow you to 'frame it'. So... the answer is that depending on the site, you may or may not be able to do this. Most likely not with the sites you were hoping.